# How to solve this recursive integral equation?

Tags: integration

I have this equation:
$$ y(x) = a + \int_0^x \left( b - \int_0^t c y(s)\; ds \right)\; dt $$

$( a,b,c \in \Bbb R$ are constants $)$

But I cannot wrap my mind around how to solve it.
If $x$ is equal to $0$ then it is easy, but I cannot find any value that works for $x > 0$.

Please help, I'm lost.

Comment: maybe you could indicate in the appropriate places over what variable you are integrating.

Comment: I know values of A, B, C. I need to get value of Y if I have value of X.

Comment: You’re missing my point.  $\int dy y\, C\ne \int dx y \, C$.

Comment: You need to specify that you are integrating w.r.t. $x$ or $y$ (I.e. $\mathrm dx$ or $\mathrm dy$ is missing)

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not very proficient in math. I am integrating dx.

Comment: Also have a look at your question as I have edited and formatted math in a better way, just to ensure that I haven't edited anything wrong.

Comment: Thank you, everything looks great.

Comment: You shouldn't have one variable do more than one job in the same equation.  Here $x$ is doing three: two integration variables and one global variable.  I suspect you mean 
$$ y(x) = a + \int_0^x \left( b - \int_0^t c y(s)\; ds \right)\; dt $$

Comment: Robert, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

$$ y(x) = a + \int_0^x \left( b - \int_0^t c y(s)\; ds \right)\; dt $$
This kind of equation is called "Integral Equation".
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left( b - \int_0^t c y(s)\; ds \right)_{\text{for }t=x}= b - \int_0^x c y(s)\; ds$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\left(cy(s) \right)_{\text{for }s=x}=-cy(x) $$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-cy(x)$$
This is a classical second order linear ODE. I suppose that you can take it from here. While solving it, two arbitrary constants appear. Put back your result $y(x)$ into the integral equation and check to make it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate

$$ y(x) = a + \int_0^x \left( b - \int_0^t c y(s)\; ds \right)\; dt $$

twice, and you get a well-known differential equation.  Initial conditions come from substituting $x=0$ here and in the expression for the derivative.

Comment: If you have time, can you provide an example for: a = 0, b = 10, c = 0.1 and x = 10? Thank You!

Comment: If you follow my hint, you'll be able to provide the example yourself.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea what you mean under "Differentiate twice".

Comment: I am doing it right? $$ y(x) = a + \int_0^x \left( b - \int_0^t c y(s)\; ds \right)\; dt $$; $$ y(x) = a + \int_0^x \left( b \right)\; dt - \int_0^x \left( \int_0^t c y(s)\; ds \right)\; dt $$; $$ y(x) = a + bx - \int_0^x \left( \int_0^t c y(s)\; ds \right)\; dt $$; but what is next?

Comment: Differentiate = take the derivative (of both sides of the equation).  The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus will be useful.